# Removing the table of contents when publishing in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I remove the table of contents when publishing in Matlab?

I have not seen an option to do this in the publish documentation. It would seem redundant to have a table of contents for very short publications.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of a way to disable the table of contents. This solution avoids a table of contents whilst maintaining cell formatting for running code, *this comes at the cost of not having section titles* - instead replacing them with simple bold text.

However if sections are not named they will not be produced...
so one solution is to modify all section starts from

```
%% Title in table of contents
```

to

```
%%
% *Title not in table of contents*
```

The first section title can be kept as a title for the document, and if all other sections are changed in this way no TOC will be produced.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying all section starts (cf. answer by RTL) from

> `%% Title in table of contents`
>
> to
>
> ```
> %%
> % *Title not in table of contents*
> ```

you may prefer

```
%% 
% <html><h2>Title not in table of contents</h2></html>
```

To compare both, the output corresponding to the following example is provided below:

```
%% Minimal working example

%% Title in table of content
% 
% Bla bla 0

%%
% *Title not in table of contents 1*
% 
% Bla bla 1

%%
% <html><h2>Title not in table of contents 2</h2></html>
% 
% Bla bla 3
```

Output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToCyC.png]

One can see that the format of the title looks closer to the actual Matlab reference when using `<html><h2>`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using a custom 'stylesheet' (as it's referred to in the documentation for 'publish').  Note: these are 'xsl' *transformations* and **not** 'css' type style sheets.

The xsl stylesheet file defines the transformation from an internal parsed XML DOM representation into the html format, and this transformation is what generates the TOC.

The default xsl file for me is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\matlab\codetools\private\mxdom2simplehtml.xsl
```

Yours may be in a similar location.  If you are unsure, you can find the path to the default xsl by setting a breakpoint within Matlab's 'publish' function and watching where exactly it loads its default stylesheet from.

Copy this file to your working folder and edit it.  The portion that generates the TOC looks like this:

```
<xsl:if test="count(cell/steptitle[not(@style = 'document')])">
  <xsl:call-template name="contents">
    <xsl:with-param name="body-cells" select="$body-cells"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

Either remove this section or comment it out with XML comments.

Then publish using the 'stylesheet' option to refer to your modified xsl file.

Comment: This worked for me for HTML output. The XSL and M files for other formats seem to have a similar section for the table of contents, they may be able to be tweaked as well.